# can't open file 'python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, slurm

I am writing a job submission script for SLURM workload manager. First, I have loaded anaconda2/4.5.12 (including Python 2.7) module. Then, I have created the Conda environment with Python3.6 version. I try to submit the script using "sbatch" command, but I get this error "python: can't open file

```
python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is an example of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=taxjob
#SBATCH --nodes=4

#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=3
#SBATCH --time=0-03:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=shortq 
#SBATCH --mem=24GB 

#SBATCH --output=/home/s.e/tax/Ftest-%j.out
#SBATCH --error=/home/s.e/tax/Ftest-%j.err
RUNPATH=/home/s.e/tax/
cd $RUNPATH

source /home/s.e/.bashrc
source activate py36
python  test.py
```

Comment: Probably missing python in your path

Comment: Please include the script as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers. I added python to PATH and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RnD says it could be just a problem of PATH: what is the answer when you `echo $PATH` the line after the `source...` ? Maybe also you need to call `python3`rather than `python`.